# Swift Presentation Style Programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, swift5

I have a button which opens a view.
But i want to present the view as a Modal view like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5JhQ2.jpg)

How can i make it?
I dont have storyboards in my project so everything is coded
I tried to look it up on google but couldn’t find anything useful.
The solution can be a Pod too

Comment: Check [DeckTransition](https://github.com/HarshilShah/DeckTransition), [SPStorkController](https://github.com/IvanVorobei/SPStorkController), [LNPopupController](https://github.com/LeoNatan/LNPopupController), and [PullToDismiss](https://github.com/sgr-ksmt/PullToDismiss) out.

Comment: Thanks, DeckTransition looks nice :)

Comment: The picture shows what you get by default in iOS 13 when you present a view controller. No special code needed at all.

Comment: @rmaddy i know but im on ios 12

Comment: You didn't mention that in your question.

Comment: Yeah. But I already got answer so thank you and sorry for the misunderstanding